# How to print the value of tensorflow object after applying a conv-pool layer on it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

After applying this on a tensorflow Variable, I am only able to get the shape of the object,
How to get the value of the variable after these layers?

```py
def model_part2(a):  
    #q=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    p=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(192,1)(a)
    #print(p.eval())
    p=tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(1,2)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256,1)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(1,2)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(512,1)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(1,2)(p)
    return p
```

`

Comment: You first need to pass some input data to the compiled Keras model. The `p` is a Layer Tensor and will hold the past layers meta-data.

Comment: I have called the function like q=model_part2(data) where data=tf.constant(1.0,shape=[128,8192,1]), then how to print the value stored in q, it only shows the shape of q.

Answer (score 1):

In **`Tensorflow Version 2.x`**, it is pretty straight forward. Working code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a =tf.constant(1.0,shape=[128,8192,1])

def model_part2(a):  
    #q=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    p=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(192,1)(a)
    #print(p.eval())
    p=tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(1,2)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256,1)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(1,2)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(512,1)(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(p)
    p=tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(1,2)(p)
    return p

q = model_part2(a)

print(q)
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  ...
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  ...
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  ...
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]

 ...

 [[0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  ...
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  ...
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]

 [[0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  ...
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
  [0.06378555 0.00853285 0.03427356 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]], shape=(128, 1024, 512), dtype=float32)
```