# How to get the latent vector as an output from a cnn model before training to the fully connected layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am working on CNN model using Tensorflow frames in google collab. I am unable to extract the latent vectors from the convolutional layers. I want to extract the output of the convolutional layers, the layers before fully connected layer.
I have tried with the following code

```
a = dropout()(classifier_model.output)
print(a)
```

I am unable to understand the solution suggested on the link [Stackoverflow solution to print the value of tensorflow object after applying a-conv-pool-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325339/how-to-print-the-value-of-tensorflow-object-after-applying-a-conv-pool-layer-on)

Anyone with any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_layer` method of the Model class to get a layer by its name, find bellow an example with a *dummy* 1D CNN and a binary classifier :

```
timesteps = 100
nfeatures = 2

# build the model using the functional API
# example of a 1D CNN inspired by the your stack overflow link, but using a model instead of successive *raw* layers
# the values of the Conv1D filters and kernels are different
input = Input((timesteps, nfeatures))

p = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=10)(input)
p = ReLU()(p)
p = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(p)
p = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=10)(p)
p = ReLU()(p)
p = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(p)
p = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10)(p)
p = ReLU()(p)
p = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, name='conv1Dfeat')(p)  # give a name to the CNN output
# fully connected part
p = Flatten()(p)
p = Dense(10)(p)
# could add a dropout layer to ease optimization
finaloutput = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(p)

# full model
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=finaloutput)

# compile network, i.e. define optimizer, loss and metrics
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

You need to train the model using the `fit` method with some data. Then you can get the output of the layer which name is `conv1Dfeat` (the last layer of the convolutive part) by defining the model:

```
modelCNN = Model(inputs=input, outputs=model.get_layer('conv1Dfeat').output)
modelCNN.summary()
```

If you want to get the output of the convolutive part, let's say based on a single numpy input array of shape (timesteps, nfeatures), you can use the `predict` of the Model class on **batched** data:

```
data = np.random.normal(size=(timesteps, nfeatures))  # dummy data
data_tf = tf.expand_dims(data, axis=0)  # convert to TF tensor and add batch dimension at the same time
cnn_out_np = modelCNN.predict(data_tf)
cnn_out_np = np.squeeze(cnn_out_np, axis=0)  # remove batch dimension
print(cnn_out_np.shape)

(4, 64)
```